# Data is not getting captured in mongodb

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb

Data is not getting captured in mongodb . For frontend I am using angular and at backend I am using node js. I tested the backend api using postman , data is getting captured in mongoDb , where as when I am submitting from an angular form data is not getting captured.

```
 //UI logic

<div class="row mt-5">
    <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h3>Register</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <form>
                     <div class="form-group">
                         <label>Email:</label>
                         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" [(ngModel)]="registerUserData.email" email required>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                         <label>Password:</label>
                         <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" [(ngModel)]="registerUserData.password" required>
                     </div>
                    <button (click)="registerUser()" class="btn btn-info float-right">Register</button>
               </form>
         </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>

//service 

private urlR="http://localhost:3000/register";
  private urlL="http://localhost:3000/login";

  constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient) { }

  registerUser(abc){
    return this.httpClient.post<any>(this.urlR,abc);
  }
//submit method
registerUser() {
this.authService.registerUser(this.registerUserData)
.subscribe(
  res=> console.log(res),
  err=> console.log(err)
  )
  }
//backend node
app.post('/register' , (req,res) => {
    const newUser = new Expo({
        email:req.body.email,
        password:req.body.password
    });
    
    newUser.save( (err , registeredUser) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.status(200).send(registeredUser);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you seeing any (network?) errors?

Comment: One possible issue can be that you need to initialize the `this.registerUserData`. I'm curious if there are any runtime errors in the console?

Comment: No . there are no runtime errors.When i am trying to register , I could see the following output in console 
```{_id: "5fe190829bf22745b86fbc70", __v: 0}
__v: 0
_id: "5fe190829bf22745b86fbc70"
__proto__: Object```

Comment: no there are no network errors as well

Comment: @JSONDerulo 
No . there are no runtime errors.When i am trying to register , I could see the following output in console {_id: "5fe190829bf22745b86fbc70", __v: 0} __v: 0 _id: "5fe190829bf22745b86fbc70" __proto__: Object